# Swift Struct is Codable but can't encode

Tags: swift, encoding, alamofire, decoding, codable

```
struct KOTextPrompt: Codable {
    let prompt: String
    let response: String
}
```

I have a very simple struct that is Codable. I'm been trying to pass this as a parameter using Alamofire and got a crash

```
2019-07-31 14:52:00.894242-0700 Kirby[8336:1685359] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'
```

I tried printing the code below and got "false". What am I doing wrong?

```
let gg = KOTextPrompt(prompt: "testprompt", response: "testresponse")
        print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(gg))
```

Comment: Making your struct `Codable` allows it to be encoded with a `JSONEncoder`, not `JSONSerialization`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `gg` which is an instance of `KOTextPromptit` is not a valid JSON object. You need to encode your struct:

```
struct KOTextPrompt: Codable {
    let prompt, response: String
}
```

---

```
let gg = KOTextPrompt(prompt: "testprompt", response: "testresponse")
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(gg)
    print("json string:", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    print("json object:", jsonObject)
} catch { print(error) }
```

This will print

> json string: {"response":"testresponse","prompt":"testprompt"}
>
> json
>   object: {
>       prompt = testprompt;
>       response = testresponse; }